# has_many :through связки моделей в active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеется 3 модели
Item:

```
has_many :ItemColors
has_many :DetailColors, :through => :ItemColors
```

ItemColor:

```
belongs_to :Item
belongs_to :DetailColor
```

DetailColor:

```
has_many :ItemColors
has_many :Items, :through => :ItemColor
```

схема ItemColor:

```
t.string   "name"
t.integer  "item_id"
t.decimal  "size"
t.integer  "detailcolor_id
```

ItemColor у каждого Item может быть сколько угодно

подскажите как я могу получить список size + detailcolor.name из ItemColor для каждого Item на странице Items в active_admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.DetailsColors.map { |i| [i.size, i.DetailColor.name] }`

Кроме того, придерживайтесь общепринятого стиля именования, как описано [здесь](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#models)

Comment: Большое Спасибо, map помог, единственное что, там надо было item.ItemColors.map вместо item.DetailsColors.map, не столь важно, главное список получается)
Может вы еще подскажете по [вопросу](http://hashcode.ru/questions/150515/ruby-on-rails-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-update-%D0%B2-active_admin) ?